The usb_device pkg on Flutter Web in release-mode gives error when trying to connect
I am using this Flutter package: usb_device 1.0.2
In debug mode, my Flutter Web Application successfully connects to my USB-Device.
My USB-device is an ESP32-S3.
And I am on Flutter version 3.24.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
(Dart 3.5.4 • DevTools 2.37.3)
I tried in Chrome, Edge and Safari Browsers.

I am able to successfully connect my USB-device
with the usbDevice.requestDevices(...) cmd inside the browser.

However, if I run my Flutter Web Application in release mode, then the device connection-popup does not show up and an error occurs.
i.e. if I try to run my Flutter Web app with the following cmd (i.e. in release mode), then the device-connection code crashes:
flutter run -d chrome --release

Here is my call of the connect method inside Flutter Web:
  Future<void> _connectToDevice() async {
    try {
      pairedDevice = await usbDevice
          .requestDevices([DeviceFilter(vendorId: 0x303a, productId: 0x1001)]);
    } catch (e) {
      Utils.showSnackBar(e.toString(), Colors.red);      
      setState(() => _status = 'Error: $e');
    }
  }

And the following error message is shown:
Invalid argument: Instance of 'minified:UK'

Again, in debug-mode, the very same code works. Its only if I run the Flutter Web App in release mode (i.e. flutter run -d chrome --release where things crash at that connection-request - i.e. right at the moment when calling pairedDevice = await usbDevice.requestDevices(...)
What can I do to make my Flutter Web application run in release mode?

This did not help, unfortunately. The moment the error message popps up, there is no verbose-message in the terminal at all. Also, with --profile or also in debug, the code works fine. Only if I run in release-mode then the error happens. i.e.flutter run -d chrome --release --verbose

When released, did you try to watch the console in the browser to see some error? Also try to implement  isSupported() from this packege to try different approaches.

Which files do you refer to ? What is your solution ? Or do you only confirm the issue ?

In the meantime, I have found a workaround:
I now use this Flutter package, called web_usb
And with some modifications to fit my device (especially concerning the endpoint-addressing), I have a working solution now that fully works also if running in release mode:
flutter run -d chrome --release

As of the other library usb_device I did not understand the described security issue from the answers and how to circumvent it. Maybe you can show a concrete example ?
